# Display posts from only one post form in custom query and exclude in main query

Tags: wp-query, functions, tags, archives, pre-get-posts

I am trying to first display four posts with post-format-aside (all assigned to current tag) and then display the "real" archive (exclude post-format-aside) for the specific tag.
Right now I am using a function to exclude post format-aside from the main query:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'keyl_get_emp_posts');
function keyl_get_emp_posts($query) {
if (is_tag()) {
if ($query->is_main_query())
 $taxq = array(
    'tag' => $current_tag,
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array(
            'post-format-aside'
          ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
);

    $query->set('tax_query',$taxq);
}

}
```

Than I am trying to display the custom query with only post-format-aside with

```
<div class="row">
<?php $current_tag = single_tag_title("", false);
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tag' => $current_tag,
    'post_type' => array('post', 'renvoeringsdamm'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside' )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
      wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
</div>
```

But the special query for only post-format-aside is displaying post from all types of post-formats... So my question is really, what is wrong with what I have done so far!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suspect that your `tax_query` is failing you, but actually your `tag` parameter is. [`single_tag_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title) returns the **name** of the tag, not the slug.

All tag and category queries are converted to a `tax_query` in the `WP_Query` class before being passed to the `WP_Tax_Query` class to build the relative string for the SQL query. Term names and slugs gets sanitized before validation and before getting the term ID of the passed term/s. (*Just for interest sake, read why you should not use term names and the `name` parameter inside a `tax_query`, check my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/180673/31545)*)

Now, slugs **should** always be lowercase and multiple words separated by hyphens. You are passing a name as a slug. Because the term name matches nothing in the term slug column (*because you have told the `tax_query` to look in the slug column*), `WP_Tax_Query` accepts that the term is invalid and does not exist and therefor simply bails out and return an empty string. This is where the big flaw comes in (*which in my opinion is a bug that should be fixed*). `WP_Tax_Query` sends an empty  SQL join string back to `WP_Query`, `WP_Query` wrongly reads this as if there were never a `tax_query` and continues to build and then executes the SQL without the join clause. This unexpectedly then returns **all** posts regardless, where in my opinion it should just return no posts at all. This is what you are seeing

So lets look at a solution and also clean up your code and make it more reliable

First, your `pre_get_post` action

- Add a check to target the front end only, otherwise back end queries will be affected as well
- Set `is_tag()` to the current instance
- Get the current `tax_query` on the tag page and modify it to add the the post format section and pass that as a new `tax_query`

You can adjust your code to something like this: (*I'm using closures, but you can revert to the old style as in your question ;-)*)

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($q) 
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only targets front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only targets the main query
         && $q->is_tag() // Only targets tag archive pages  
    ) {
        // Gets the current tax_query
        $tax_query_obj = $q->tax_query->queries;
        // Add the post format query part to the current tax_query
        $tax_query_obj[] = [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ['post-format-aside'],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ];
        //Build a proper tax query
        $tax_query = [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $tax_query_obj
        ];
        // Set the modified tax_query
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

        // Set any additional parameters here except tag parameters
    }
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

As for your custom query, we can get the current tag ID being viewed by simply using `get_queried_object_id()` and then using that in a `tax_query` with our post format . You can try the following in your arguments: (*Requires PHP 5.4+ due to new short array syntax (`[]`)*)

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', // Default tag taxonomy
            'terms' => get_queried_object_id(), // Gets current tag archive tag ID
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-aside'
        ],
    ],
    // Rest of your arguments excluding tag parameter
];
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping me! Although this function seem to "error/whiten" my theme and I can't figure out what part is troubling. I have tried to change the closures to arrays but still can't understand what is wrong.. :(

Comment: You should upgrade your php version. I will however rewrite the code for older versions. Please note, all versions older than PHP5.4 is not supported anymore and therefor a huge security risk to your site:-)

Comment: This is really strange, in mamp it says I am running php version 5.5.3 and it doesn't work even when copied your new code. Must this be a php error or could it be something else? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Good crap, there is a copy and paste error in my code. Don't know how it creeped in. Sorry about that. Will correct now

Comment: It should work now, sorry for setting you off on a made goose chase :-)

Comment: Hahhaa thank you noticed it on my way in to town - didn't have internett connection tho so couldn't wright.. This works like  a charm! But do you understand why your first code didn't work when it said mamp was using PHP 5.5.3. Is there any other PHP update I must do for my localhost to upgrade? :))

Comment: Jip, had a stupid syntax error, that is why you got the white screen, which is normal for PHP syntax errors. Funny thing is, I tested it last night locally and was shocked when you said you got a white screen, somewhere between copying and pasting it in my answer, I deleted a underscore in the following line `$q->is_main_query()` so it ended up as `$q->is main_query()`, which triggered a PHP syntax error. Your PHP version is good to go as-is ;-)