# How to query Posts from a custom post type which contains a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have the following:

```
$queryResponse = new \WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_date',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'term'     => $dateSelected
        )
    )
));

var_dump($queryResponse);
```

`$dateSelected` is '2015'.

I want: All posts from post type of portfolio with a custom taxonomy of portfolio_date (Actual name: Portfolio Date. This is what the user sees) that has the value of, in this case,  2015.

So if I create 6 posts under portfolio, with the portfolio date of 2015, I should get back 6 posts. Right now I get: 0 posts.

I do have 1 post under this post type with this taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

You have one or two issues here and possible future bugs that you might encounter

- `term` in your `tax_query` should be `terms`
- Be carefull with terms having dates as names and especially dates as slugs. This can cause issues and unexpected results if custom permalinks clash or if something falls into the template hierarchy for some reason.
- Never use the `name` field in a `tax_query`. There is an issue with the sanitizing of the term name before the join clause is constucted for the SQL query in the `WP_Tax_Query` class. This is a known bug that will propably be there for many versions to come.

  I have explained the complete issue in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/180673/31545) I have recently done, so feel free to go read the whole 9 yards. But in short, what basically happens is, `WP_Tax_Query` uses `sanitize_title_for_query` to sanitize the input from the `name` field in a `tax_query`. This function strips all whitespaces and special characters and also convert all capitals to lowercase. So a term name like `My Term Name/2` gets converted to `my-term_name2` which will fail as that term name does not exist.

  In short, as precaution, do not use the `name` field in a `tax_query`, rather use `term_id` or `slug`. If you do not know these values, then use `get_term_by()` to get the term ID or slug from the name and then pass that to the `tax_query`
- You should also make sure that you can query posts from your custom taxonomy and custom post type publically. Make sure that have the correct values set when you register the post type and taxonomy